# How to find the magic number of a file by just provding the path of the file using c++?

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("/root/ds/filehandling/a.pdf", "rb");
    unsigned char magic[4];
    fread((void *)magic, 1, 4, fp);
    cout << hex << "magic:";
    for (int i = 0;  i < 4;  i++)
        cout << " 0x" << int(magic[i]);
    cout << dec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is I have to specify the extension then only i would get the magic number , but my objective is to specify the name of file without giving its extension so that on comparing magic number i could determine its type.

This is what i want:

int main()
    {

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("/root/ds/filehandling/a", "rb");
    unsigned char magic[4];
    fread((void *)magic, 1, 4, fp);
    cout << hex << "magic:";
    for (int i = 0;  i < 4;  i++)
        cout << " 0x" << int(magic[i]);
    cout << dec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ouput : magic: 0x25 0x50 0x44 0x46

but I a m getting "SEGMENTATION FAULT"

Comment: So, you want to specify `a` as the file name and get `a.pdf` as the file opened?  What do you wan to have happen if a.txt also exists in the directory?

Comment: if possible read both files magic number

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Please take some time and ask a better question. You could for instance provide us with a wished user code and expected output/side-effect. Example: "I with to call `get_magic("/path/a")` which will return a list of filenames and associated magic number, the magic number of a file being..."

Comment: Is it possible to just provide path of the file without specifying the file type

Comment: I want to determine the magic number of a file

Comment: You don't provide a file type anywhere in your question. An extension is not a file type, it's merely part of the filename.

Comment: Open the directory, read the directory's contents, and save the names of all files that have a matching name and any extension. Then handle each file found (if any) individually using the existing code. Shouldn't take more than a few minutes to add these bits to your existing code. That seems rather obvious, so what exactly is your question? How to read the contents of the directory? `opendir()` and `readdir()`. See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: Sorry that's what i meant i dont wan't to take extension as an input

Comment: Can you use C++17?  If so you can use the utilities in [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to get all of the files in a directory.  If not you should be able to use boost.

Comment: The "extension" part (`.pdf`) is just part of the file name and says nothing about the contents of the file except by convention. You can not open a file without its **full name** so what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: *"what i meant i dont wan't to take extension as an input"* Then do what Sam Varshavchik said.

Comment: How would your program behave if there was both `a.txt` and `a.pdf` in the same folder? Which one would it open in your scenario?

Comment: Thankyou everyone,i understood my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a segmentation fault because there is no such file as `/root/ds/filehandling/a`, and `fopen` thus fails, but you never even check its return value. `fp` is going to be `nullptr`, and passing that to functions like `fread` is just begging for trouble.

The question really has nothing to do with magic numbers; if you want to open a file without knowing its extension (i.e. not knowing its full name), you will have to [look in its directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612097/560648) and find the file you want by pattern matching. Note that there may not only be just one; e.g. if there's a file `a.txt` and a file `a.pdf`, you're going to have to decide which one you pick for the search term `"a"`.

Remember, the file's "extension" is just the last part of its name; it's just a convention. Many files don't even have such a thing!

By the way, don't forget to `fclose`.